# Get item from browser local storage with python

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to read out with Python the value of a key I've placed in to the browser via Javascript.
Is there a simpler way to do this then with `selenium` ?
It seems like a lot of hassle to use `selenium` just to get a `localStorage` item.

Javascript to place username in to `localStorage` :

```js
userName = window.prompt("Please enter your name", "Name...");
localStorage.setItem("name", userName.toString());
```

Is there a Python equivalent of `localStorage.getItem("name")` from Javascript ?

Comment: Why would there be? Python and the web browser have very little to do with each other.

Comment: try : driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.getItem('key');")

Comment: Thanks, guess there is no way around selenium then

Answer (score 1):

For anyone just as new to the whole thing as me, I solved it now by doing what everyone else was saying in the other answers to similar questions and used Post to send the key value from localstorage to python. As the user has to upload a file anyway I created with javascript the upload form dynamically and used an input element of type hidden to send the key in a variable (as we are talking about the user name which is obviously different from user to user) to python

```
function createUploadForm(){
    let userName = localStorage.getItem("username");
    let form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("action", "/upload");

    //create hidden input element for user ID
    let userID = document.createElement("input");
    userID.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    userID.setAttribute("id", "userID");
    userID.setAttribute("name", "userID");
    userID.setAttribute("value", userName);
```

and on python site I received this via flask (@app.route)

```
user = flask.request.form.get("userID")
```

Answer (score -2):

As I know, only Javascript can interact with the browser (client-side), and it's the only native web client-side programming language. Local storage is a browser feature, so you can access this feature only by using Javascript. Python can't do anything in this situation.

Comment: Browsers also support [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/). You can write code in many different languages like C, C++, Go, Rust or AssemblyScript and transpile/compile to WebAssembly